# Play! 2.0 database overwrite on application start. (MYSQL)

Tags: java, mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Every time I run my Play! application, I am told my database needs an evolution. This overwrites the information I currently have in the db, What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of playframework are you using ? 1.X or 2.X ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, when you're using auto generated evolutions in your project, Therefore after first run, you should disable it (by removing first 2 commented lines  from `1.sql`) and switch to manual evolutions.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Evolutions

Of course in next evolutions you need to use `ALTER`s instead of `CREATE`s for modifying existing structures

Comment: Do I have to keep the first evolution script as it was? I delete the parts that drop tables and they end up being written back in. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I wrote **REMOVE** two first lines (they are commented)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Datasource attached to the application.conf that may be acting like a DB reset? I mean like a Bootstrap.

I worked with Play framework but I didn't see it, in Grails you have a config option for DB to drop, update or create database on application start. Check if this config option is available on Play and if it´s look if you have it set.

The application.conf document would be interesting to see, can you put it here with sensitive data deleted?.

Hope it helps.